# Java mapping FileTypes with Folder Locations

Tags: java, oop

looking for a good design solution in Java for the following requirement

Based on the type of file which can be known through the filename we have to move the file to specific shared folder, for example if the file is a zip file i have to move to "zipped" location or if it is non zip file then a different location and so on

With the filename and extension we will be able to know what type of file it is, and there is a chance that more rules can be added in the future hence i wanted to avoid complex if-else or switch statements

for example if the file name is IN_MAH_MUM-_20190306162024X_CANCER.xml, this is not a zip file and it contains "CANCER" word in it hence it will go to "CANCERFILES" folder

basically looking for mapping between file types and folder locations in an efficient way

**Below is an example**

**Types of Files**

- Zipped
   Move to "Zipped" folder
- Unzipped

  - Medical
  - CancerFiles
      Move to "CancerFiles" folder
  - CardioFiles
  - OrthoFiles
  - Non Medical
  - FinancialFiles
  - OccupationFiles

**Code for Mapping - Getting values from json file**

```
Map<String,String> mapFileTypeLocations = new HashMap();        
mapFileTypeLocations.put(fileTypes.getAsJsonObject().get("cardioTypeFiles").getAsJsonArray().toString(),locations.getAsJsonObject().get("cardioFilesLocation").getAsString());
    mapFileTypeLocations.put(fileTypes.getAsJsonObject().get("financeTypeFiles").getAsJsonArray().toString(),locations.getAsJsonObject().get("financeFilesLocation").getAsString());
```

This mapping may not work efficiently if requirement demands to add more conditions like based on time zone, country code, city code that are part of filename

Answer (score 0):

The goal of a structure is to access efficiently the data.
If you organize the folder by type and inside the by postcode, you assume that the type is more important than the postcode.
If you organize the folder by postcode and inside the by type, you assume that the the location s more important than the type.

Even if it may look scary a database could be the simplest solution.
For a relational database, assuming a single table FILES with two columns, type and postcode (just a simple case). With a simple query you could aggregate the files in the way you prefer (or are required). You could use an embedded DB like [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) or [HSQLDB](https://hsqldb.org)

However, because your requirements seem still vague, instead of a relational db I would suggest a more advanced option using [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/).
MongoDB allows you to add new fields to your metadata (type, postcode, etc...) without impacting the db structure because you just update the json document associated with that file. Even more, MongoDB allows you also to store files so, for a general solution, you could be independent from the filesystem too.

As your groups are sill not clear is difficult to to tell you which is the best structure, however here are few points for your case

- you can have a reliable file type and metadata analysis using [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)
- for the mapping configuration file yaml is a cleaner format than json (Spring Framework uses xml or json for the configuration, not json)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion, the actual purpose of this to automate testing functionality of log files being moved to different folders based on the file extension and some metadata from the file name

Comment: Hello Sri, I added few lines trying to follow your requirements. Regards.